# Create Python UDF in Redshift to replace character from a string

Tags: python, replace, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

I have a varchar column in my DB. It should have values like '43', '43000', '50000' etc. but sometimes it has values like '43,000', '50,00,000' etc. and also sometimes it has garbage values with other characters in it.

What I want to do it first replace all `','` from the values then try and convert it to an `int`, if it succeeds then return this `int` value. Otherwise return `null`. I'm trying to write a Python UDF for it but it doesn't seem to work. Here it is:

```
create or replace function isnumeric (aval VARCHAR(20000))
  returns int
IMMUTABLE 
as $$
    try:
       aval = aval.replace(',','');
       x = int(aval);
       return x;
    except:
       return (1==2);
       return null;

$$ language plpythonu;

select 

isnumeric(field1) 

from 
table
limit 10000
```

Can anyone help me please??

Comment: Could you show us the output and/or errors the program is giving? We can help more if you tell us exactly what it is and isn't doing.

Comment: @TechPerson I'm getting Invalid operation: invalid input syntax for type boolean: "null";

Comment: Your UDF should return `int`, not `bool`. There is no concept of `null` in Python. Instead, it uses `None`.  I'm not how Redshift handles it if you `return None`, but it _might_ translate it to `NULL`. Give it a try. (Or, frankly, use Joe's `CAST` idea below, which is better.)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein For Joe's idea below, I mentioned in the comment why it can't be used. And I tried replacing null to None, but still the udf returns a boolean only.

Comment: It returns a boolean because the 2nd line says "returns bool".

Comment: Oops!! 
After changing it and simply doing:
select 
isnumeric1(field1) 
from table1, I'm just getting 0 values in that column.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a UDF in my opinion. You can use `REGEXP_INSTR` to find invalid values and then use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to clean up non-numeric characters from valid strings.

```
WITH test_vals AS 
    (          SELECT 'garbage_1' test,   'xx43,000' val 
     UNION ALL SELECT 'decimal'   test,  '43,000.00' val 
     UNION ALL SELECT 'commas'    test,  '50,00,000' val 
     UNION ALL SELECT 'date_val'  test, '2019/03/03' val 
)
SELECT test
       --Any character other than numbers, commas or decimal returns NULL
     , CASE WHEN REGEXP_INSTR(val,'[^0-9,.]') > 0 THEN NULL 
       --Commas are removed, decimal marker is retained
       ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(val,'[^0-9.]','') END::NUMERIC  AS ouput 
FROM test_vals
;
```

Output is:

```
   test    |  ouput
-----------+---------
 garbage_1 |
 decimal   |   43000
 commas    | 5000000
 date_val  |
```

Comment: But the problem is I only want to replace ',' and if the column value contains any other character, I just want to convert it to a null and not consider that value in my calculations.

Comment: The reason for this is that if the column contains values like 43,000 converting them to 43000 is valid. However some garbage values include 2019/03/03 but converting it to 20190303 is not correct as this column is a price column and somebody entered a garbage date value instead. So I want to ignore it in my calculations.

Comment: Revised the example to address the use case of removing invalid entries. However, I would advise caution at this point. If the data is completely free form then any deep analysis is likely to be unreliable at best. Good luck.